# Why is the potential function defined differently in physics and calculus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, convention

I am very familiar with the concept of a potential function, and potential energy, from calculus-based physics.

For instance, if we have the familiar force field $\mathbf{F} = -mg \,\mathbf{j}$, then a potential function is given by $U = mgy + C$. (Since potential energy is relative, we have an infinite number of potential functions.)

Notice that the gradient of the potential function is the negative of the force field: $$\nabla U = \nabla(mgy + C) = mg \,\mathbf{j} = -\mathbf{F}.$$

That was perfectly fine with me. But now in vector calculus, I am reading that the potential function $f$ of a vector function $\mathbf{F}$ is such that $\nabla f = \mathbf{F}$. A negative sign appears to have been lost when migrating from physics to calculus.

It seems confusing to call $f$ a "potential function", since it cannot be interpreted as potential energy in the real world. So why is the calculus nomenclature as it is (i.e., why not call this something else and then say the potential function is the negative of it)?

Comment: You will encounter differences in definitions like this frequently, for example the constant in Fourier series/transform, $z$ vs. $z^{-1}$ in the Z transform, etc., so the best you can do is to adapt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading further on in my calculus textbook, I found that they later defined the potential energy as the negative of the potential function.

So it appears that the reasoning presented in my question was correct, but that some sources simply use a slightly different definition for "potential function" – not because it corresponds to potential energy, but because a convenient name is needed for it.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_potential) says that the gradient of the potential is the negative of the vector field, but that "In some cases, mathematicians may use a positive sign in front of the gradient to define the potential."

Answer (score 4):

Recall where the negative sign comes from in physics -- it is simply due to your coordinate system and point of view. The difference is analogous to the difference between work done by gravity and work done on gravity.

Comment: Up is positive but gravity acts downwards.

Comment: You could also view it as putting your "zero point" for potential at the "infinity cloud" as my physics teacher called it.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. It seems to me that no matter what coordinate system you use, the potential energy should increase when you move against the force, which implies a negative relationship no matter what. Regarding your last sentence, what do you mean by "work done on gravity"?

Comment: $W_{on} = -W_{by}$. Gravity was not a good analogy; maybe work done by or on a gas during a thermodynamic process would have been better.

Comment: Okay, but you still have not answered my question. (I.e., I do not see how one's coordinate system and point of view would introduce a negative sign into the particular situation about which I am asking.) If a different analogy would explain what you mean, do you think you use that analogy in your answer instead of gravity?